# tf.keras Functional model gives different results on the same data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have defined my Functional model like this:

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling='avg')
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = preprocess_input(inputs)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x, training=True)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

The problem is when I call .evaluate() or .predict() I get slightly different results everytime when using the exact same batch (with shuffle=False in my dataset, and all the random seeds initialized).
I tried reconstructing the model without some of the layers and I found the culprit to be these 2 layers constructed by the line x=preprocess_input(inputs), which give randomness to the results:
[model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjpBN.png)

Note: preprocess_input is a vgg16 preprocessing function at tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input.

However, if I redefine my Functional model as Sequential:

```
new_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
new_model.add(model.layers[0]) #input layer
new_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(preprocess_input))
new_model.add(model.layers[3]) #vgg16
new_model.add(model.layers[4]) #dropout
new_model.add(model.layers[5]) #dense
```

The problem is gone and I get consistent results from .evaluate() or .predict().
What could potentially cause the Functional model to behave like this?

**EDIT**

As xdurch0 pointed out, it was the dropout layer at fault for different results. The functional model applied dropout during .predict() and .evaluate() methods.

Comment: You are adding a dropout layer with `training=True`, which leads to random dropout being applied.

Comment: It seems you are right. My previous understanding was that during .predict() or .evaluate() model would always run in inference mode (automatically setting training=False). Do you know how to set training=False to turn off dropout when running these methods?

Comment: Simply do not set the `training` argument (that should include the `base_model` btw) when building the model. I _suppose_ what happens right now is that you setting it during model construction overwrites the usual behavior (true during training, false during inference) and always sets it true.